# Function Handles in Julia

Tags: callback, function-pointers, julia, function-handle

What is the standard way to define a callback function, or a function handle in Julia?

Suppose I define

```
function myFun(a, b, c, d)
 a - 3* b - c * d # The return value
end
```

My goal is to fix b = 1, c = 2, d = 3, and pass myFun as a function of a.
Something like:

```
newFun2(x) = myFun(x, 1 ,2, 3)
myReceiver(myFun2)
```

Comment: … that should work just fine.  What's the issue?

Comment: The problem is when I pass the function handle that defines an objective in the way above to a solver (NLOpt) to minimize the objective, I receive an error like myFun2 has no methods matching my usage ..

Comment: Are you misspelling `newFun2`?

Comment: Yes sorry newFun2 I meant.

Comment: So the problem should be with the requirements of  the solver. :-) I just wanted to double check the function handle format in Julia, since I was not sure about it. Thank you Matt B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/NLopt.jl), the objective function for `NLOpt` should be of the form:

```
function f(x::Vector, grad::Vector):
    if length(grad) > 0:
        ...set grad to gradient, in-place...
    return ...value of f(x)...
end
```

Thus, the code would need to look something like:

```
function myFun(a, b, c, d, grad)
    a - 3* b - c * d # The return value
end

newFun2(x, grad) = myFun(x, 1 , 2, 3, grad)
```

`myFun()` would have to compute the values of the `grad` vector as well as returning the objective function value, if it was to work successfully with optimization algorithms that use the derivative information that `myFun()` is required to write to `grad`.